# Shorthand to declare "return type" in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm following [Typescript handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes) to learn about class.

Here is one of the examples:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

var greeter: Greeter; // return type: Greeter
greeter = new Greeter("world"); // implement greeter variable
alert(greeter.greet());
```

In typescript:

```
var greeter; // return type: any
var greeter: Greeter; // return type: Greeter (implicit convertion `any` to `Greeter`)
```

So, my question is: If we know exactly about the return type, why can't we use `Greeter` instead of `var` keyword?

What I wanna archive:

```
Greeter greeter = new Greeter("world"); // same to: var greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done to keep consistency with javascript.
The type definition can be omitted and TypeScript will automatically infer the type of the variable.

```
var greeter : Greeter = new Greeter();
```

Is the same as

```
var greeter = new Greeter();
```

This is slightly beside the point but you can also declare a variable that can hold multiple types.
For example

```
var a : Greeter | number
```

Will hold a Greeter or a number. Having the type definition after the variable name is more elegant in my opinion.

Comment: I think typescript can do it before translating to javascript code. I'm talking about `typescript syntax`. Do you agree?

Comment: No, it's still more consistent to keep the js way. Also keep in mind that you can use let or const to declare different kinds of variables.

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler than that. You can actually do

```
var greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

The compiler is smart enough to infer the type from there.

EDIT: I'm sorry. I had misunderstood the question as if you didn't know about this syntax. The one the other answers mentioned is mostly what you want. That is:

```
var greeter: Greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

You can't go the Java way here since we are talking about different languages. It shouldn't take too long for you to get used to it. This is a really minor thing.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to accomplish is just not possible because it is not TypeScript syntax.

If you want to specify the type of a variable it is done like this:

```
var greeter: Greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

There are a lot of similarities to both Java and C# but the type system in TypeScript is different especially in syntax.

Comment: ya, You understand mine exactly. But why not? I mean: typescript can do something (converting `Greeter greeter = new Greeter()` to `var greeter = new Greeter()` automatically). typescript compiler can do that

Comment: If you'd like to suggest new language features, I'd suggest you submit an issue on the typescript repo on github... https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues